# Which is better: going to learn poorly for a week, or to miss one day to learn better the rest?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, choleh-sick

Let’s say someone is sick. Laryngitis. Hardly able to speak. He’s able to go to learn, but it’s extremely difficult and painful. If he goes, he will learn poorly because of his condition, and he will continue learning poorly throughout the week as a result of not resting his throat. *Or,* he can miss one day, rest up, and feel good as new the next day, to learn well for the remainder of the week. Which is better? Is it better to learn even though it’s difficult and a lower quality, or is it better to miss one day in order to learn more easily and better the other six?

I ask both in terms of schar (if we even know), and in terms of practicality.

Comment: I’m not sure that this is limited to a case of a sick person, but this is a more common case and so I thought to ask it in this example.

Comment: אחד המרבה ואחד הממעיט ובלבד שיכוון לבו לשמים

Comment: שאין אתה יודע מתן שכרן של מצוות

Comment: לפום צערא אגרא?

Comment: נושאי המיטה, חילופיהם וחילופי חילופיהם פטורים...

Comment: I asked R' Moshe Luria Z"l this exact question and his answer was **"it all depends on his Tikkun"**.  But this only holds for Chassidishers who believe in Tikkunim, though.

Comment: @AlBerko "believe in Tikkunim"??? Even non chasidisher people believe in tikunim! Do you think that The Vilna Gaon or the chafetz chaim disagreed that people need to be metaken what they messed up??

Answer (score 2):

See Menachos 99b

> ביטולה של תורה זהו יסודה דכתיב (שמות לד, א) אשר שברת אמר לו הקב"ה
>   למשה יישר כחך ששברת
>
> The apparent dereliction of the study of Torah is its foundation,
>   e.g., if one breaks off his studies in order to participate in a
>   funeral or a wedding procession. This is derived from a verse, as it
>   is written: “And the Lord said to Moses: Hew for yourself two tablets
>   of stone like the first, and I will write upon the tablets the words
>   that were on the first tablets, which [asher] you broke” (Exodus
>   34:1). The word “asher” is an allusion to the fact that that the Holy
>   One, Blessed be He, said to Moses: Your strength is true [yishar
>   koḥakha] in that you broke the tablets, as the breaking of the first
>   tablets led to the foundation of the Torah through the giving of the
>   second tablets.

From this we learn that sometimes breaking off from the study of Torah for the purpose of improved learning in the future, is considered a fundamental part of Torah learning itself.

Regarding the Schar (reward) see Rashi (ibid):

> שביטולה של תורה - כגון שמבטל תורה להוצאת המת ולהכנסת כלה זהו יסודה
>   כלומר **מקבל שכר כאילו יושב ומייסדה ועוסק בה** שנאמר אשר שברת ולא אמר
>   ליה בלשון כעס שמע מינה הסכימה עמו דעת השכינה כשביטל תורה ושיברן כיון
>   דנתכוין לטובה:
>
> For the withdrawal of Torah - for example one who withdraws from
>   learning Torah to escort the deceased and for ushering in the bride
>   this is the foundation of Torah meaning to say **he receives reward as
>   if he is sitting and learning** as it says that you have broken and it
>   does not say it with anger implicating that G-d agreed with his action
>   when he eliminated Torah when breaking the tablets since he intended
>   for the good:

So not only is there no problem with doing so, but even during the time when he is not learning he receives reward as if he is sitting and learning

Comment: I see Rashi discusses a case of הוצאת המת and הכנסת כלה - why do you assume this applies for learning as well? Maybe when it comes to learning one should push ahead anyway rather than rest up one day and continue the next.

Comment: @DonielF because ביטולה is referring to ביטול תורה, which is what your question was about.

Comment: Then why does Rashi limit the case to הכנסת כלה והוצאת המת?

Comment: @DonielF You asked " why do you assume this applies for learning as well?" Rashi is giving an example as to why the person is **not learning**, but it is still a question of Bitul Torah , so Rashi also is saying that "this applies for learning" - not "as well" but that is the whole question!

Comment: But the examples Rashi brings are ones where a person is *obligated* to stop learning (Megillah 28a). You can’t bring a proof from there that to stop learning for learning’s sake is also okay - you’d need to prove from elsewhere that it’s also an obligation, or at least permissible, before you can apply that Rashi.

Comment: @DonielF To me it is a קל וחומר.  Take it from the Schar. If when stopping for bikur cholim you get schar "as learning" although the bikur choliim has nothing to do with the learning itself, surely so for learning itself.

Comment: I can ask a פירכא on the קל וחומר - you say this by those for which there is a חיוב to interrupt, will you say this where there’s no חיוב to interrupt? If you can demonstrate from elsewhere that there is indeed a חיוב to interrupt, great, but I don’t see how you can prove that from here.